# How can i reach a class variable from another class in Lua?

Tags: class, lua, coronasdk

I am using director class for scene transitions and i need to use the variable in a class in another class. So how can i call it?

```
     local a= require "welcome"
```

variableName is text display object in welcome class

```
     print(a.variableName.text)
```

However i get nil.

Could you help me out? Thanks

Comment: Lua doesn't have classes. Can you explain more effectively what happens within `welcome`?

Comment: Here take a look at director class http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/director-class-10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the variable a property of the returned table:

```
local Class = {}

function Class.new()
    local class = {}

    class.variableName = display.newText("Hello mom!", 100, 100, "Helvetica", 18)

    return class
end

return Class
```

Then you can reference it:

```
local a = require ("class").new()

print(a.variableName.text)
```

**OR**

If you want to pass variables between the screens in Rauber's Director Class, you can:

```
local parameters = {p1="some text", p2="some more text"}

director:changeScene(parameters, "sceneName")
```

In your screen, make the new function accept the parameters:

```
function new(parameters)
    print(parameters.p1, parameters.p2) --> some text   some more text
end
```

**OR**

Put _G in front of your variable

```
_G.myGlobalVar = "some awesome stuff"
```

Then you can reference it in another class

```
print(_G.myGlobalVar) --> some awesome stuff
```

Comment: Thank you for all these wonderful answers, Royi. It helped a lot. =)